# Symfony2 forms collection

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have, two entities, Topic and TopicContent are relation by topic_id.

topic_id in topic table is autoincremet , in topic_content it's not autoincrement.

Because, i need to get topic_id from Topic entity when query it's ok, and then insert data in topic_content table. Help me please, how to do this in symfony with orm. thanks.

TopicContent

```
namespace Socialist\ClubBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="topic_content")
 */
class TopicContent
{
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="topic_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     *
     */
    protected $topic_id;


    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="topic_text", type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $topic_text;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Topic", inversedBy="topicContent", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="topic_id", referencedColumnName="topic_id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $topic;


    /**
     * Set topic_id
     *
     * @param integer $topicId
     * @return TopicContent
     */
    public function setTopicId($topicId)
    {
        $this->topic_id = $topicId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get topic_id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getTopicId()
    {
        return $this->topic_id;
    }

    /**
     * Set topic_text
     *
     * @param string $topicText
     * @return TopicContent
     */
    public function setTopicText($topicText)
    {
        $this->topic_text = $topicText;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get topic_text
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTopicText()
    {
        return $this->topic_text;
    }

    /**
     * Set topic
     *
     * @param \Socialist\ClubBundle\Entity\Topic $topic
     * @return TopicContent
     */
    public function setTopic(\Socialist\ClubBundle\Entity\Topic $topic = null)
    {
        $this->topic = $topic;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get topic
     *
     * @return \Socialist\ClubBundle\Entity\Topic 
     */
    public function getTopic()
    {
        return $this->topic;
    }
}
```

Topic

```
namespace Socialist\ClubBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="topic")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Topic
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $topic_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=200)
     */
    protected $topic_title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $topic_date_add;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $topic_date_edit;

    /**
     * Get topic_id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getTopicId()
    {
        return $this->topic_id;
    }

    /**
     * Set topic_title
     *
     * @param string $topicTitle
     * @return Topic
     */
    public function setTopicTitle($topicTitle)
    {
        $this->topic_title = $topicTitle;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get topic_title
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTopicTitle()
    {
        return $this->topic_title;
    }

    /**
     * Set topic_date_add
     *
     * @param \DateTime $topicDateAdd
     * @return Topic
     */
    public function setTopicDateAdd($topicDateAdd)
    {
        $this->topic_date_add = $topicDateAdd;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get topic_date_add
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getTopicDateAdd()
    {
        return $this->topic_date_add;
    }

    /**
     * Set topic_date_edit
     *
     * @param \DateTime $topicDateEdit
     * @return Topic
     */
    public function setTopicDateEdit($topicDateEdit)
    {
        $this->topic_date_edit = $topicDateEdit;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get topic_date_edit
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getTopicDateEdit()
    {
        return $this->topic_date_edit;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function setTopicDateAddValue() {
        if (!$this->getTopicDateAdd())
        {
            $this->topic_date_add = new \DateTime();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function setTopicDateEditValue()
    {
        $this->topic_date_edit = new \DateTime();
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setTopicDateAdd(new \DateTime());
        $this->setTopicDateEdit(new \DateTime());
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="TopicContent", mappedBy="topic", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private   $topicContent;

    /**
     * Set topicContent
     *
     * @param \Socialist\ClubBundle\Entity\TopicContent $topicContent
     * @return Topic
     */
    public function setTopicContent(\Socialist\ClubBundle\Entity\TopicContent $topicContent = null)
    {
        $this->topicContent = $topicContent;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get topicContent
     *
     * @return \Socialist\ClubBundle\Entity\TopicContent 
     */
    public function getTopicContent()
    {
        return $this->topicContent;
    }
}
```

[image]

Topic Entity

```
    public function __construct()
{
    $this->topicContent = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->setTopicDateAdd(new \DateTime());
    $this->setTopicDateEdit(new \DateTime());
}

 /**
 * Set topicContent
 *
 * @param \Socialist\ClubBundle\Entity\TopicContent $topicContent
 * @return Topic
 */
public function setTopicContent(\Socialist\ClubBundle\Entity\TopicContent $topicContent = null)
{
    $this->topicContent = $topicContent;

    return $this;
}
```

Topic Controller

```
    public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Topic();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('topic_show', array('id' => $entity->getTopicId())));
    }

    return $this->render('SocialistClubBundle:Topic:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Comment: To begin, are you sur that you need a one to one relation ? In your case, one topic get one content ?

Comment: yes my friend, i nee a one to one relation! i've been updated my post, look at please :)

Comment: The problem is not coming from your entities (and also doctrine). It seems to work. You just should `setTopicContent()` when you create the Topic in your controller.

Comment: yes, you're right!, but how i can set id in TopicContent entity? i've updated post, .. look at pls :)

Comment: please see the answer i posted,I think that is what u expect

Comment: Oh, I'm slow on the uptake. If the id from topic and topicContent are identical remove the one from topic content. By retrieving your topic entity you can do `$entity->getTopicContent()->getId()`. So just replace the topic_id in Topic content by an id which you doesn't matter. I don't know if I'm clear but to sum up you don't need to re-add the topic_id in entity topic_content.

Comment: >remove the one from topic content - where is ???? >So just replace the topic_id in Topic content by an id which you doesn't matter. - where is ?????

Answer (score 0):

After persisting your Topic Entity, you will get LastInserted topic id from your Topic entity
for example,

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

   $topic = new \Acme\TestBundle\Entity\Topic();
   $topic->setTopicTitle('Your Title');
   $em->persist($topic);
   $em->flush(); //insert data into table
```

If insertion is ok `$topic` entity hold new row object inserted
You can get new topic id by getting

```
 $newTopicId= $topic->getTopicId();
```

For Topic content Entity,

```
$topicContent= new new \Acme\TestBundle\Entity\TopicContent();
$topicContent->setTopicId($newTopicId);
$topicContent->setTopicText('Your topic text');
```

For avoid more confusion Please change your Topic Content Entity as follows,

```
namespace Socialist\ClubBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="topic_content")
 */
class TopicContent
{
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     *
     */
    protected $id;


    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="topic_text", type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $topic_text;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Topic", inversedBy="topicContent", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="topic_id", referencedColumnName="topic_id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $topic;



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set topic_text
     *
     * @param string $topicText
     * @return TopicContent
     */
    public function setTopicText($topicText)
    {
        $this->topic_text = $topicText;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get topic_text
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTopicText()
    {
        return $this->topic_text;
    }

    /**
     * Set topic
     *
     * @param \Socialist\ClubBundle\Entity\Topic $topic
     * @return TopicContent
     */
    public function setTopic(\Socialist\ClubBundle\Entity\Topic $topic = null)
    {
        $this->topic = $topic;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get topic
     *
     * @return \Socialist\ClubBundle\Entity\Topic 
     */
    public function getTopic()
    {
        return $this->topic;
    }
}`
```

The `id` should be primary key and autoincrement
this will resolve your all 'topic_id' burdens

Comment: lookt at my post, i've been added the code of my topic controller. Any ideas?

Comment: From your database design I think no need of topic_id in topic_content entity, cause you have set a relation with $topic in topic content

Comment: otherwise please set the relation with topic_id in topic_content it will resolve the issue

Comment: >  please set the relation with topic_id in topic_content ???? how to do this?? i think that i have now in my entities?

Comment: for now, a question it's how to get autoincrement id from database, when i create a new topic...

Comment: that question doesn't have a logic

Comment: Nisam, i know that with * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY") , it's work, but i don't need the autoincrement id topicContent entity.

Comment: That was I said to you @user2531518. You should put an identifier 'which doesn't matter' to respect the SQL structure. Because you can already retrieve the topic id from `$entity->getTopic()->getId()`. The update of answer is that you should achieve. Sorry if I'm ambiguous.